# External SVG not shown when embeded as IMG src

Tags: html, svg

I'd like to show an externally saved SVG within a `img` tag by using its `src` property:

```
<img src="https://combeespecs.blob.core.windows.net/configurations/55919877060821504/DefaultView.svg" style="width: 300px;">
```

For some reason the image is not shown at all. If I embed the same SVG inside an `object` tag, everything works just fine:

[image]

Here's the complete code used in the [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f09yx0Lw/2/):

```
<div>SVG in IMG tag:</div>
<img src="https://combeespecs.blob.core.windows.net/configurations/55919877060821504/DefaultView.svg" style="width: 200px;">

<div>SVG in object tag:</div>
<object data="https://combeespecs.blob.core.windows.net/configurations/55919877060821504/DefaultView.svg" type="image/svg+xml" style="width: 200px;"></object>
```

One more thing: I'd like to use the `img` tag instead of `object` since I'd like to show that SVG inside a HTML-Mail and the `object` tag seems to be blocked by most mail clients.

Comment: I would recommend you stick with actual images (.jpg, .png) for email. Support for SVG is still quite low.
https://css-tricks.com/a-guide-on-svg-support-in-email/

Comment: I'm aware of that but can't switch to images right now for technical reasons. Also it's fine for me since that email is only sent to a very limited set of users which all use the same mail client that basically supports SVG in img tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use SVG in an image context it must be complete in a single file. So the embedded png, since it's external to the SVG file won't be displayed.

To work around this you'll need to convert the png into a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) so it's completely embedded within the svg file.